# How to access global variable from main Node.js module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have simple app.js that contains simple variable, e.g.:

app.js

```
const HW = "Hello, world!";
var config = require('./config');
```

How do I access that HW variable from config.js?
config.js

```
console.log(HW);
```

does exports in app.js really set it visible in config.js?

Comment: Well it's not a global variable but rather a module variable.

Comment: No, the `exports` object doesn't "set anything visible". It provides what can be `require`d from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see a variable declared in another js file, you have to export it in that file and import/require it in the file which needs a reference to that variable. So if you have a const variable in app.js named HW, you have to export 
it:

app.js

```
const HW = "Hello, world!";
module.exports.HW = HW;
```

And then import it in your other file:

config.js

```
var HW = require("app.js").HW;
console.log(HW);
```